# Dividing a elements into a group

Tags: java, algorithm

I am giving N elements and their weight , and i have to pick up only M elements out of them such that their weight is divided by k.

```
For Ex:
N=5
Weight:1 2 3 4 5
M =3
K=5 
so we will pick up : 1 4 5 as total 10 is divide by 5. So ans =10
```

My approach : using Recursive function

```
public static  int ans(int[] a,int m,int k,int total){
        int sum=0;
        if(a.length<m)
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        if(m==0){
            //System.out.println("ok");
            if(total%k==0)
                return total;
            else
                return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        int[] temp = new int[a.length-1];
        for(int j=0;j<temp.length;j++)
            temp[j]=a[j];

        sum =  Math.min(ans(temp,m,k,total), ans(temp,m-1,k,total+a[a.length-1]));




        return sum;
    }
```

But this approach fails for very large amount of data , can someone help me how to use **dynamic programming** in this , so that i don't make a repetitive calls.

Comment: The requirements aren't clear to me. What about the first three elements (with weights 1, 1, and 3)? They also add up to weight 5. Generally, there is more than one possible solution. Additionally, there could be no solution. What should your algorithm provide? I also see, that you return only an int. How could that be a solution?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose[link](http://www.codechef.com/problems/BUYING)

Comment: How about grouping input values by their remainders 'mod K'...?

Answer (score 0):

Get a flag array which flags for each of your elements whether they are included in the result or not. Start from nothing being included, and recursively try for each element if inclusion of it can provide a right result or not.